# Merge two arrays like this

Tags: arrays, array-merge

I have two array like this::

```
$doctor = Array(
[0] => 4
[1] => 5
[2] => 8
[3] => 35
[4] => 41
[5] => 42
)

$clinic = Array(
[0] => 1
[1] => 3
[2] => 9
[3] => 15
[4] => 19
[5] => 20
)
```

Now i want to add these array like this

```
 $all = array(
 [0] => 4
 [1] => 1
 [2] => 5
 [3] => 3
 [4] => 8
 [5] => 9
 [6] => 35
 [7] => 15
 [8] => 41
 [9] => 19
 [10] => 42
 [11] => 20
```

I have tried this but it is not my expected output:

```
$all = array_merge( $doctor , $clinic );
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop to do that

```
$all=[];
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
$all[]=$doctor[$i];
$all[]=$clinic[$i];
}
```

if you don't have same length for the arrays,
Try

```
$doctor_size=sizeof($doctor);
$clinic_size=sizeof($clinic);
$all=[];
$size=$doctor_size;
if($doctor_size<$clinic_size){
$size=$clinic_size;
}
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
if(isset($doctor[$i])){
$all[]=$doctor[$i];
}

if(isset($clinic[$i])){
$all[]=$clinic[$i];
}

}
```

Comment: It's not fix array size.Means doctor array maybe 10 and clinic array maybe 15 in that case ?

Comment: Then do you need to merge  last five clinic at end of the array?

Comment: Yes last five clinic also in array

Comment: I have changed my answer, can you check